# react native require not working for image source

Tags: react-native

Given below code, react native complains

```
Requiring unknown module "../../images/Foo.png".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".
```

But the same code works fine if I hardcode the image source path in `require` call.

**Code not working**: has a method call to determine icon name. Notice the `require('../../images/'+imageIconNameFor(prediction.type)` line.

```
const PredictionItem = ({prediction}) => (
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => itemPressed()}>
    <View style={styles.predictionItem}>
        <Image style={styles.predictionIcon} source={require('../../images/'+imageIconNameFor(prediction.type))}></Image>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
);
function imageIconNameFor(predictionType) {
    return "Foo.png";
}
```

**Code working**: Instead of calling a method to determine icon name, if I hardcode the icon name in `require` call, it works fine. Notice the `require('../../images/Foo.png')` line.

```
const PredictionItem = ({prediction}) => (
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => itemPressed()}>
    <View style={styles.predictionItem}>
        <Image style={styles.predictionIcon} source={require('../../images/Foo.png')}></Image>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
);
function imageIconNameFor(predictionType) {
    return "Foo.png";
}
```

Why is there a different behavior when I concatenate strings to build image source?
Why `require('../../images/'+imageIconNameFor(prediction.type)` fails to render image but `require('../../images/Foo.png')` works fine? 
Note that method call was not a problem. Error message contains the complete path of the image computed using the method call. In spite of the complete path, react native complained about missing module with require.
React native version is **0.37.0**. I tested this on ios-simulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is how react-native packager works, the image name in require has to be known statically. Here is example from official [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/images.html):

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') :     require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```

Comment: Thanks . I overlooked the docs . I assumed concate works . Thanks for providing the answer

Comment: not working brother... My image path is comming from json so i have to give variable in require function so what i have to do

Comment: @M.HassamYahya you may use `source={{ uri: variable.urlPath }}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

make sure give some style like this

<Image source={{uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'}}
style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />